# Converting legacy project to Maven by bundling multiple jars

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have a legacy java project (A) that contains multiple subprojects (A.1, A.2...) that are all dependent on each other.  I am now using Maven for future projects (B, C...), but am looking for a way to have our CI push this recompiled dependency project (A) into our repository every time a change is made.  The subprojects (A.1, A.2...) are built in different ways (shell script, ant build, etc) and I have been able to get Maven to successfully execute those.

My question is, how can I get Maven to bundle up all of the jars that were created from these build scripts (A.1, A.2...) into a single jar (A) for publishing to the repo?  It looks like build-helper may be able to do what I need but it doesn't seem like I can use wildcards for those artifacts.  Is there something that better fits my situation?

Edit: Want to clarify that the overarching maven project (A) does not have any code or any entry point.  All I want to do is reference the projects contained (A.1, A.2...) by having future projects (B, C...) download (A) using maven.  Is this even do-able?  Splitting each subproject (A.1, A.2...) into maven projects independently is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using Maven to push pre-built jars to our repo after build was complete using `build-helper-maven-plugin` and its `attach-artifacts` execution step

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional module that just takes care of the bundling and configure inside it the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). Your "shade" module would depend on all the other modules and Maven would build it in the end.

So this plugin can crates an "uber-jar" that contains all the stuff from your individual other modules - provided that those create JARs in the first place. If those are build by all kinds of different scripts... I'm not entirely sure what they might create.